# Лагерная "тройка", "тройка" НКВД – нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, названия

В сети встречаются разные написания, чаще – с кавычками. Как их объяснить?

- Предложения такие:

> *По приговору лагерной "тройки" отец Анатолий был расстрелян в 1937 г.*
>
> *29 октября 1939 г. тройка при НКВД осудила священника на 8 лет
>   лагерей.*

Answer (score 3):

Выражения ТРОЙКА НКВД или ЛАГЕРНАЯ ТРОЙКА часто употребляемы, устойчивы и вполне понятны, поэтому их оформление без кавычек не только приемлемо, но и предпочтительно.

Другое дело, когда из контекста не сразу понимаешь, о каких именно тройках идёт речь, когда нет ключевых слов НКВД, ЛАГЕРНАЯ и т.д. В этом случае кавычки уже уместны как знак, выделяющий слово, употреблённое в особом, необычном значении. Ср.:Тройка НКВД, которая убила моего прадеда И.И. Вениаминова ***(к 75-летию создания «троек»).*** ([Палачи](https://igorkurl.livejournal.com/168460.html))